# como actualizar un div sin enviar parámetros con ajax y php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Necesito que un **div** **se actualice** de acuerdo a lo que selecciono que hago en una lista sin recargar la página,pero no se cómo hacerlo siempre he mandado parámetros, pero esta vez solo quiero *traer los valores de mi archivo php* sin mandarle nada.

código ajax:

```
function actualizar_div(){               
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            $.ajax({
                type : "",
                url : "actualizacion_fase.php",
                data : null,
                success : function(data){
                   $("#container_1").html(data);
                }      
            })    
            return false;               
       }  
}
```

código de mi lista:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a  href="#" onclick="actualizar_div();" class="list-group-item active">ACTUALIZACION DE ESQUEMA</a>
                    <a  href="#" onclick="actualizar_div();" class="list-group-item ">PACIENTE CON FALTAS REITERATIVAS</a>
                    <a  href="#" onclick="actualizar_div();" class="list-group-item ">PACIENTES RESPONSABLES</a>
                </div>                         
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

código del div que se recarga:

```
 <div id="container_1" class="container">

 </div>
```

Comment: ¿Y no te responde? Porque no importa que no envíes parámetros en data:{} vació que no es lo mismo que null, más bien hay que ver tu archivo PHP para ver que esta contestando. O en dado caso, porque no lo esta haciendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function actualizar_div(){               
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "actualizacion_fase.php",
                success : function(data){                      
                   $("#container_1").html(data);
                }      
            })    
            return false;               
       }  
}
```

Comment: Como aclaración hacer solo `$(...).html(data)` reemplaza todo lo que contiene el elemento seleccionado por lo tanto no es necesario `$(...).html("")`, el funcionamiento es diferente de `.append()`

Comment: vamos editando :D gracias por la aclaración hermano :D